# Challenges with Bit.dev Setup on Windows: Facing 'Module not found' & 'Version not installed' Errors Despite Troubleshooting Efforts. Need Assistance

Tags: reactjs, open-source, bit.dev

I'm currently in the process of setting up Bit.dev on Windows, and I'm encountering a series of issues. Initially, I was receiving "module not found" errors. Despite adding the path manually, the problem persisted. I then decided to uninstall and reinstall Bit, but I'm still facing the same challenges.

I have been following this documentation: https://bit.dev/docs/quick-start/hello-world/#install

I would greatly appreciate some guidance on how to troubleshoot and overcome these obstacles. I tried running these commands on PowerShell, CMD and MINGW64 still nothing is working

[Module not found error. Node and npm packages are up to date]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbslt.png)

[version 0.2.24 is not installed error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n01pl.png)

I tried all the things that I mentioned earlier.